# Publishing to IIS 8.5 and error 502.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I always have bad times publishing to IIS 8.5

I have a old project in .NET Core 1.0, but I have made a new project, but this time, in .NET 4.5 (for several reasons)! This new project (.NET 4.5) replaced the old (.NET Core)

In Visual Studio 2015, everything works correctly, then, I build the project, and copied the files to IIS folder (`\inetpub\wwwroot`).
When I visit the page, I got a error `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure`.
Then, I remember that the APP Pool was using .NET Core, so, I changed to `.NET CLR 4.0`, but still no luck.

I don't even known where is the error LOG on IIS to see if I found anything...
I already see the logs on `%WINDIR%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` and `\inetpub\logs\`. No error on logs.

All I found about the error `502.5` is that almost always is related to .NET Core (but i'm using .NET 4.5)

Comment: Look in the event logs on the machine. Hit Start, type "Event Viewer" and press enter. Expand Windows Logs > Application and look for anything there related to your error.

Comment: Visual Studio 2016?

Comment: Tks! Failed to start process with commandline '".\SIV.exe" ', ErrorCode = '0x80070002'. Source = IIS AspNetCore Module. Is still using .NET Core! I see that is something in `Handler Mapper `. @DavidG Visual Studio 2015 (typo)

Comment: Why not just create a fresh site and app pool?

Comment: Changed the Handler Mapper order, and now receiving error 403!

Comment: @DavidG because this must run on "root" folder, and IIS already running several others "child" sites

Comment: When you say "child sites" do you mean virtual folders?

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, english is not my primary language, and IIS it's not in english! This project must be on root url, and IIS has some others sites from another system (not a virtual folder, but physical folders in `\inetpub\wwwroot\` as `IIS Application`).

Comment: I believe that the main problem was `Handler Mapper` order. This resolved the error 502.5, but now, I cannot pass the error 403 and error 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I posted on comments, the main error was because the `Handler Mapper` order.
The old project it was a .NET Core project, and the new project, is a .NET 4.5.

For some reason (or my fault), the `Handler Mapper` was all wrong.